# "Mortarboard" badge on a board with no rep?

Tags: support, reputation, badges

I have participated in one heated discussion at StackOverflow meta, and to my surprise I have earned a "Mortarboard" badge on meta profile. I wonder, how can one earn such a badge if meta sites do not add/remove reputation from upvotes and downvotes?

(On a side note, that badge announcement appeared when I've got +40/-100 votes on my answer, indicating that an upvote costs 10 and a downvote costs -2, as everywhere else.)